# Abaqus scripting: get point

Tags: python, abaqus

Is there any way to write a script which prompts for point click in Abaqus CAE?
I know the function getInput but it works only for strings.

Answer (score 2):

There is a way, but it's not that easy. You need to create a custom GUI procedure. Using simple kernel scripting will not do the job.

You should implement a custom `AFXPickStep` procedure. More information about the procedure itself can be found in Abaqus documentation: `Abaqus GUI Toolkit Reference Guide > All Classes > AFXPickStep`.

Here is a small example of a similar procedure which is used to pick nodes in Abaqus Viewer. Adapt it to your own needs.

```
import abaqusConstants
import abaqusGui


class PickNodesProcedure(abaqusGui.AFXProcedure):

    def __init__(self, owner):
        abaqusGui.AFXProcedure.__init__(self, owner)

        self.cmd = abaqusGui.AFXGuiCommand(
            mode=self,
            method='pick',
            objectName='node_set',
            registerQuery=abaqusGui.FALSE
        )

        self.nodesKw = abaqusGui.AFXObjectKeyword(
            command=self.cmd,
            name='node',
            isRequired=abaqusGui.TRUE
        )

    def activate(self):
        return abaqusGui.AFXProcedure.activate(self)

    def getFirstStep(self):
        self.pickStep = abaqusGui.AFXPickStep(
            owner=self,
            keyword=self.nodesKw,
            prompt="Pick nodes",
            entitiesToPick=abaqusGui.NODES,
            numberToPick=abaqusGui.ONE,
            sequenceStyle=abaqusGui.TUPLE
        )
        return self.pickStep

    def getLoopStep(self):
        return self.pickStep


toolset = abaqusGui.getAFXApp().getAFXMainWindow().getPluginToolset()

toolset.registerGuiMenuButton(
    buttonText='Pick Nodes',
    object=PickNodesProcedure(toolset),
    kernelInitString='import kernel_module',
    applicableModules=abaqusConstants.ALL,
)
```

Note that this does not include the kernel script which is needed to process the selected entities.

Comment: Thank you. I'll try

Answer (score 0):

how do you call this inside? Using RSG you just do the following and the button to select appears:

```
RsgPickButton(p='DialogBox', text='Select a face:', keyword='myFace', prompt='Pick a face', entitiesToPick='MDB_GEOMETRY|FACES', numberToPick='ONE')
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please edit to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.